# How to define Kafka (data source) dependencies for Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to consume a kafka 0.8 topic using spark-streaming2.0.0, i'm trying to identify the required dependencies i have tried using these dependencies in my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

when i run sbt package i'm getting unresolved dependencies for all three these jars,

But these jars do exist

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11/2.0.0

Please help in debugging this issue, I'm new to Scala so please let me know if i'm not doing something right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying the Scala version *and also* using `%%` which tries to infer which Scala version you're using.

Either remove one `%`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

Or remove the Scala version:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % "2.0.0"
```